# Issue with driving multiple LEDs via transistors

Tags: arduino, led, transistors, npn

I am attempting to individual control multiple LED-based light sources via PWM.  Now I am somewhat familiar with transistors and their usage, and had no issue setting up one instance of this control scheme.  However when I added more transistors to the circuit, I ran into a problem.  It seemed that only one PWM signal, would control *all* of the lights.  I am new to schematics and schematic design so I could use some help figuring this out.  The schematic, as I think I built it, is below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW8nxN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The wiring was done with [this article](http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/) as reference, specifically the "light" example.

The power source is 12V 6A, which is more than enough to drive the lights I am using, which are 12V LED boards.  I won't be using an Arduino in the final implementation, but I am using it currently for testing, so assume that is where the PWM is coming from.  Oh, and the transistors are TIP31 NPN units.

As I said previously, the issue is that when using the circuit, the lights will only respond to one PWM signal and they will both use that value seemingly.  Otherwise it works just fine.  My only thought is that it could be an issue with them sharing a common ground?  But if so, what is the best way to isolate them?

Comment: I also forgot to show that the SOURCE of the PWM signal is also connected to common ground.  For testing that would be the arduino.

Comment: Is there connection between the arduino ground and your \$12V\$ DC source?

Comment: You have nothing limiting the current in your LEDs-  You need some series resistance. Also 330 ohms is a lot of pull-down resistance, a few Kohms would be fine.

Comment: So I have done so more testing.  I have successfully gotten the arduino to give individual pwm values.  To answer your comment @nidhin, both cases seem to work.  Arduino ground connected, and not connected.  But with slightly different light characteristics...

And to answer your question John D, I am aware, the actual led units I will be using are 12V LED boards with built in resistors.  I simplified for the purpose of the question.

Comment: And to be more clear, the product I need to actually use to give PWM in the end is this phidgets board.  [link](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=26&product_id=1032_0).

I seem I have been able to make the arduino work correctly, but not the phidgets board.  It does not work without the ground connected to the common ground, and when receiving two PWM signals, both LEDS seem to use the highest value.  The board is designed to allow individual PWM values, up to 64 of them.

Comment: I did speak with a Phidgets rep at one point, and he mentioned something about that particular board sharing a common VCC and using PWM on the ground.  Is it possible that I need to redo my schematic in reverse?  Such that the ground goes through the collector, and the VCC is connected to the emitter?  Does that make any sense?

Comment: @asaalger - to change the common signal to +ve you need to use PNP transistors - the emitter is still  common (so goes to your +ve voltage)

Comment: @MartinThompson Do you think that might be the source of the problem?  I would have to buy some PNP transistors to test with if that is the case.

Comment: Do you have a link to the LEDs you are using?

Comment: @asaalger - It looks like the board you've linked to is designed for driving LEDs directly, so you shouldn't need any transistors actually...

Answer (score 1):

The article you referenced uses MOSFET transistors, not a BJT like the TIP31. The big difference is that a MOSFET is a voltage-triggered (high impedance) device while a BJT is current-triggered (low-impedance) device. The result of this is that with an NPN transistor, you need a series resistor to limit the current flowing from the arduino IO pin through the transistor base. Without this, you are likely to damage the Auduino and/or the transistor. Try putting a 510 ohm resistor between each source and base and remove the pulldown resistors.